# PEAR error require_once(Structures/Graph/Node.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I'm trying to install PHPUnit using PEAR. Whatever command i run like `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit`, `pear install Structures_Graph`, `pear upgrade`, `pear upgrade --force --alldeps`... it always ends with

> Warning:
>   require_once(Structures/Graph/Node.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such  file
>   or directory in
>   PEAR\Structures\Graph.php on line 37
>   PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(Structures/Graph/Node.php):
>   failed to open stream: No  such file
>   or directory in
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR\PEAR\Structures\Graph.p
>   hp on line 37
>
> Warning:
>   require_once(Structures/Graph/Node.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such  file
>   or directory in
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR\PEAR\Structures\Graph.php
>   on  line 37 PHP Fatal error: 
>   require_once(): Failed opening
>   required 'Structures/Graph/Node .php'
>   (include_path='C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\pear') in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4
>   \PEAR\PEAR\Structures\Graph.php on
>   line 37
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed
>   opening required
>   'Structures/Graph/Node.php' 
>   (include_path='C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\pear') in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR
>   \PEAR\Structures\Graph.php on line 37

I tried [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717547/cant-install-pear-on-windows-7-structures-graph-error) and downloaded and extracted the ZIP to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR\PEAR, but that only replaces the [Structures_Graph](http://pear.php.net/package/Structures_Graph) error I had before with this one.

PEAR is installed with go-pear.bat on a wamp installation on Windows 7, PHP 5.3.4.

What more can I try to make this work?

Update: It should be said that I've tried to change the include_path reported in the error above, to no success. Tried to alter both `php.ini` and `pear.bat`.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, I have not had the time to pursue this further yet. I think I may have gone around this problem before by installing PHPUnit manually.

Comment: I found that the version of go-pear.phar that comes with WAMP is rotten. I downloaded a new version of pear(1.9.2), replaced that file and installed it as per normal. I had a lot of problems with %PATH% but eventually it worked after restarting.

Comment: Do you have a file `Structures/Graph/Node.php`? Which full path has it?

Comment: I have the same problem and tried all the solutions you give but not works. Anybody can solve this?

Comment: Answer for this is found here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717547/cant-install-pear-on-windows-7-structures-graph-error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717547/cant-install-pear-on-windows-7-structures-graph-error

Comment: @qais: Thanks, but I stated in my question that that solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I found that the version of pear (`go-pear.phar`) which comes with wamp is basically broken.

Downloading a fresh `go-pear.phar` file from pears website worked for me.

Comment: Nice, will [check it out](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)

Comment: Hi, I'm still stuck in this problem. I did it as above: downloading a new go-pear.phar and put it in PEAR folder. It still says "Warning: require_once(Structures/Graph/Node.php)..."

Comment: Also make sure you're using 32 bit wamp. That might help.

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggest you try it. Possibly also a system path issue. I no longer use the computer I set wamp up on, so I can't really tell you much about how I set it up.

Answer (score 2):

When I installed the files it installed some of them in path c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear\PEAR\, among the files there was the Structures directory. I simply copied all the files one direcotyr up to c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear\ and the problem has been resolved, at least for me

Answer (score 1):

Set your include path to

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR\PEAR\
```

Better start all over because that setup seems to be fckd up.

Comment: I've tried to change the include_path, but PEAR doesn't read this new (see "Update:"). I've tried this on two computers with the same result

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above with no luck.
What I had to do was edit all paths and add "PEAR/".

Graph.php

```
require_once 'PEAR/Structures/Graph/Node.php';
```

Node.php

```
require_once 'PEAR/Structures/Graph.php';
```

AcyclicTest.php

```
require_once 'PEAR/Structures/Graph.php';
require_once 'PEAR/Structures/Graph/Node.php';
```

TopologicalSorter.php

```
require_once 'PEAR/Structures/Graph.php';
require_once 'PEAR/Structures/Graph/Node.php';
require_once 'PEAR/Structures/Graph/Manipulator/AcyclicTest.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

`C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/` you should change to a complete path example:

```
require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph.php'
```

Change this in

```
Graph.php

require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph/Node.php';
Node.php

require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph.php';
AcyclicTest.php

require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph.php';
require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph/Node.php';
TopologicalSorter.php

require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph.php';
require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph/Node.php';
require_once 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/PEAR/PEAR/Structures/Graph/Manipulator/AcyclicTest.php';
```

Pear not found the path to Graph.php ect.