# regarding pear installation in xampp on windows 7

Tags: php

I am using xampp version of 1.7.4 placed in D:.But when I am executing go-pear.bat file in cmd then showing error:"Failed to open stream invalid path on 1236 line phar://go-pear.phar/index.php.
when i am tring to install pear then "unpacking failed of c://php//structure-graph is showing.
But when i run only pear then it's showing all the command.
Please help guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717547/cant-install-pear-on-windows-7-structures-graph-error

Answer (score 0):

This is may be due to a misconfiguration of include_path in your php.ini, make sure the path to the PEAR folder is part of the include_path setting, ie:

```
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
include_path = ".;D:\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

Comment: include_path is as it is as you have given.What to do lawrencealen now

Comment: Hey Thank you very much Now It's working properly.There was error in "go-pear" file.downloading of updated version worked..........:)