# Need help upgrading PEAR to install PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, zend-server

I'm trying to install PHPUnit with PEAR. Here's what I'm running...

```
PEAR Version: 1.7.2
PHP Version: 5.3.8-ZS5.5.0
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Windows NT L-PC 6.1 build 7600 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition) i586
```

When I try the install, I get an error that says I need to upgrade PEAR...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.7.2
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "channel://pear.symfony-project.com/YAML" (version >= 1.0.2)
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0)
phpunit/File_Iterator requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.7.2
phpunit/Text_Template requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.7.2
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.7.2
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/File_Iterator" (version >= 1.3.0)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/Text_Template" (version >= 1.1.1)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
phpunit/PHP_Timer requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.7.2
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.7.2
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires package "phpunit/Text_Template" (version >= 1.1.1)
phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.7.2
No valid packages found
install failed
```

So I figure I need to upgrade PEAR. I ran pear upgrade pear and got the following...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin>pear upgrade pear
pear/Console_Getopt requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.8.0), installed version is 1.7.2
downloading PEAR-1.9.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PEAR-1.9.4.tgz (296,332 bytes)
.............................................................done: 296,332 bytes

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used   any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for '-7.0/DST' instead in PEAR\Validate.php on line 489
downloading Archive_Tar-1.3.9.tgz ...
Starting to download Archive_Tar-1.3.9.tgz (18,123 bytes)
...done: 18,123 bytes

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for '-7.0/DST' instead in PEAR\Validate.php on line 489
downloading Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz (30,318 bytes)
...done: 30,318 bytes

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for '-7.0/DST' instead in PEAR\Validate.php on line 489
downloading XML_Util-1.2.1.tgz ...
Starting to download XML_Util-1.2.1.tgz (17,729 bytes)
...done: 17,729 bytes

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for '-7.0/DST' instead in PEAR\Validate.php on line 489

Warning: require_once(Structures/Graph.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in PEAR\Download er.php on line 1230

Warning: require_once(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for '-7.0/DST' instead in PEAR\Downloader.php on line 1230
```

But it doesn't upgrade.  When I re-run pear version it shows i'm still on 1.7.2. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but to get rid of the warnings you can add a timezone to your php.ini file. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php. Maybe try that and see if PEAR downloads correctly.

Comment: Looks like the main error is this one though `Warning: require_once(Structures/Graph.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in PEAR\Download er.php on line 1230
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Download and uncompress Structures_Graph from the pear.php.net website. ([Direct Link](http://download.pear.php.net/package/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz)) Note: ? may want to get a version older than your current
>      install of PEAR, though I had no trouble with the latest version
>      (1.0.4) while running PEAR 1.8.0
> 2. Move folders/files into place To find where to move this folder, if you don't know: cmdline> pear config-show Find the path for "PEAR
>      directory php_dir", which is your PEAR\lib folder
>
> "Structures" folder -> move into the "PEAR\lib" folder
>
> The rest can be deleted as they'll be created when you actually
>   install Structures_Graph, but for reference: "LICENSE" -> delete or
>   move it to "PEAR" root, or docs or wherever "docs" folder -> delete or
>   move into the "PEAR\docs" folder "tests" folder -> delete of move into
>   the "PEAR\tests" folder "package.xml" -> delete, and any other package
>   files
>
> 3. Install "Structures_Graph", Even though the files are present, Structures_Graph is not really installed yet. command line> pear -a
>      install Structures_Graph This will install the latest version from
>      your configured channel (ex. pear.php.net) The -a argument will
>      install any dependent packages as well
> 4. Upgrade your PEAR install to current version cmdline> pear upgrade PEAR
> 5. Upgrade the package Console_GetOpt. It likely was not installed properly yet cmdline> pear upgrade Console_Getopt

References:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-120958.html

[Can't install PEAR on Windows 7, Structures/Graph error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717547/cant-install-pear-on-windows-7-structures-graph-error)

Comment: My Pear directory is here...  `C:\Program Files               (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear`. I placed the Structures file inside. Ran `pear install -a Structures_Graph` but it tries to pull the tar file from online and I get the following error:  `ERROR: unable to unpack C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\tmp\Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz
`

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to grab the one forom PEAR\lib

Comment: can you try `pear upgrade-all` after doing second step (ie copying structures folder to pear folder)?

Comment: I moved the unpacked .tgz file to the temp folder and it worked!  I reran pear upgrade PEAR and it says... `pear/PEAR is already installed and is the same as the release version 1.9.4` but when i do pear version it says the version is 1.9.4. So it worked!  Thanks!